# Marklogic installation on redhat 7

Tags: linux, redhat, marklogic

I have a redhat instance on aws. I am trying to install marklogic. I got the url after signing up for marklogic developer. using the following command, I get a 403 forbidden return.

```
curl https://developer.marklogic.com/download/binaries/7.0/MarkLogic-7.0-6.x86_64.rpm?
```

Comment: Wrong site, not a programming question.

Answer (score 4):

The curl statement that you get after signing up, and clicking the download of a MarkLogic installer should include an access token. Something like:

```
https://developer.marklogic.com/download/binaries/8.0/MarkLogic-8.0-4.2-x86_64.dmg?t=xxxxxxxxxxx&email=mypersonal%40email.com
```

You may have overlooked the last bit, it looks like the UI is wrapping the long url after the ?. I suggest using the 'Copy to clipboard' button to make sure you get the full url.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to visit the site in a web browser first to register (Name, Email), and then you will get a link you can use with curl.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.marklogic.com/products/download-via-curl

You need to register an account first.  Have you done that step yet?

Comment: yes I did, I actually decided to just download to my windows box then winscp to my linux box then local installed it. Thanks.@CtheGood

Answer (score 0):

The URL will have special characters in it (the email id will at least have '@'). So wrap the URL within quotes.
For eg:

```
wget "http://developer.marklogic.com/download/binaries/9.0/MarkLogic-9.0-1.1.x86_64.rpm?t=Xtxyxyxyxx.&email=xyz.abc%40abc.com"
```